# Return last value of an and chain

Tags: php

Is there a way to return the last value in an and chain? I can do this is in Javascript but php seems to just return a boolean value.

E.g.

```
$message = ($error && "First error") || ($error1 && "Second error");
```

$message will be 1 instead of "First error". Assuming `$error = true;`

```js
var error = true;
var error1 = true;

var message = (error && "First") || (error1 && "Second");

alert(message);

error = false;

message = (error && "First") || (error1 && "Second");

alert(message);
```

Comment: Your question is not realy clear. Can you post the javascript code of what you want to do in PHP?

Comment: @MikeBovenlander updated

Comment: So you want to return first AND second error, or either ? Sorry but i am confused. Or do you want to return only second even if first is true ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ternary operator for your condition.

```
 <?php
   $error1 = true;
   $message = $error ? "First error" : ($error1 ? "Second error" : "");
   echo $message;
?>
```

live demo1 : https://eval.in/792139

live demo2 : https://eval.in/792134

Comment: yeah, but it still feels kind of verbose. Still +1 for helping

Comment: @A.Lau I tried thinking of a couple of other ways to do it but Rishi's solution seems like the best.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that i do understand you correctly, just out of curiosity - what is wrong with doing this?

```
$error1 = true;
$error = true;
if($error) {
    echo "first message";
}
if($error1) {
    echo "second message";
}
```

Comment: I return one of the other. Basically it's like Rishi's answer, but I feel like it's simplier and easier with the javascript method. You can see what I mean just by running my snippet. If either condition fulfills it, the first one that fulfills the condition will have their last value saved, e.g. the error string.

Answer (score -1):

try to use XOR 
 (0 XOR 1 ) || (0 XOR 1)  ==  1 || 1 == 1

Comment: check what I mean. I have included javascript example.

Comment: Your answer is quite vague. It is better to include a code sample. See: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)